# ImportError: No module named socketserver

Tags: python, homebrew

Disclaimer: noob

I am trying to get streamparse (https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse) up and running on my machine. I am following the tutorial found here: https://youtu.be/ja4Qj9-l6WQ?t=18m50s . I have installed leiningen and pip, but when running the command

```
sparse quickstart
```

I get the error:

```
Randalls-MacBook-Pro:streamparse randallbanks$ sparse quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/sparse", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('streamparse==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'sparse')()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/streamparse/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
import streamparse.cmdln
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/streamparse/cmdln.py", line 6, in <module>
from .ext.invoke import (list_topologies, kill_topology, run_local_topology,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/streamparse/ext/invoke.py", line 25, in <module>
from ..contextmanagers import ssh_tunnel
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/streamparse/contextmanagers.py", line 8, in <module>
from six.moves.socketserver import UDPServer, TCPServer
ImportError: No module named socketserver
```

From what I've read, this seems like an issue with the name "socketserver" differing between python2 and python3. I've tried downloading python3 to see if this remedies the issue, but I keep running into this brew error:

```
Randalls-MacBook-Pro:streamparse randallbanks$ sudo brew install python3
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

Without 'sudo':

```
Randalls-MacBook-Pro:streamparse randallbanks$ brew install python3
Error: You must `brew link gdbm' before python3 can be installed
Randalls-MacBook-Pro:streamparse randallbanks$ brew link gdbm
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdbm/1.11... 
Error: Could not symlink include/gdbm.h
/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

it seems like workarounds for this error are 'not recommended'. I tried manually downloading python3 from the website https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ , but I don't really know what I'm doing as far as installing with all of these source files. Any help for the best direction I should take for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have too old a version of the `six` library. What does `python -c 'import six; print(six.__version__)'` produce?

Comment: See https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/113

Comment: Okay, it seems like this is indeed my problem. I'm having issues updating six though, `pip install six --upgrade` yields `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

Comment: Does `pip` work? `pip -V` should confirm if you have the right version for your Python 2.7 setup.

Comment: Ah, Mac comes with their own version of `six`. Thanks Apple! This'll make upgrading harder..

Comment: pip -V yields `pip 6.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)`

Comment: Install [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and create a virtualenv to install `sparse` into. Then use `pip install -U six` in that virtual environment.

Comment: okay, this error is getting beyond frustrating. I tried `pip install virtualenv` and got a long error ending in `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'` . I'm banging my head against the wall with this constant permission denial when trying to install the packages I need

Comment: use `sudo pip install` to install into a system location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X 10.10 comes with a pre-installed version of `six` that is too old to support `sparse`.

Your best option is to create a [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install `sparse` into that. A newer version of `six` will be installed into that virtualenv when you do.

Don't try to upgrade the version provided by Apple as that may break other things.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using the system installation of Python, which comes with a version of six (1.4.1) that is too old for streamparse.

As I put in the GitHub issue, I'd recommend that most people just use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) if they're doing Python development on OS X to avoid the issues of trying to upgrade things in the system Python installation.

Comment: Hi @DanBlanchard, welcome to Stackoverflow!  As your post is a valid response, but does not attempt to answer the original question --- it would be much more appropriate as a `comment` instead of an `answer`

Comment: I agree, but I don't have 50 reputation to comment. :)